# criteria to find a point equidistant from given n points

Tags: geometry

Is there any procedure to find a point equidistant from given $n$ number of points $(n\gt2)$. Our prior assumption is that they may not form a regular polygon. Please suggest a method, that could be of any type geometric,or numerical method. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the points in the plane?

Comment: When $n=3$, such a point is the circumcenter of a triangle. When $n\geq 4$, such a point may not exist!

Comment: Lucian, Care Bear, Jack D'Aurizio ,Thanks for ur response. I have now understood. We can find a equidistant point if the perpendicular bisectors intersect. Other wise we cannot, the same thing happen when n=3 and collinear. So we can conclude that if the perpendicular bisector meet at a point that is our required point. We can hardly find such a point for n>3. Thanku

Answer (score 2):

Being equally distant from two points means being situated on the perpendicular bisector of the segment determined by those two points. Now, in the case of three points, we have two straight lines $($the perpendicular bisectors of each segment$)$, which obviously intersect in one point only,
if the three points are not collinear $($and in none if they are collinear, since the two perpendicular bisectors will in that case be parallel to one another$)$. And we know from middle-school that the perpendicular bisector of the third segment will also pass through that same point of intersection, since in a triangle the perpendicular bisectors are concurrent. Now, if the perpendicular bisector of any segment created by the addition of a fourth point will not pass through that same point, then there is no point of intersection of **all** perpendicular bisectors, and hence **no** point equally distant from all other points. Which is basically the same as what **Jack** already said in far fewer words in his very short and concise comment.

Comment: Not **necessarily** I think you mean.